# Asp.Net Core Identity in Blazor server-side

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-3.0

So is it possible to use the [Identity System](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) which we can use in other ASP.Net Core applications in a Blazor server-side application and if yes, are there any drawbacks? I am asking since I literally couldn't find anything or very little information about authentication in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.NET Core 3-preview6 just released a few hours ago and it has integrated authentication support for `blazorserverside` apps.

You can find details in the release notes: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-6/

Comment: Yeah I just noticed it as well, glad it came out, thanks for the answer :)